# Выполнение кода, приходящего в виде текста по Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть кое-какой код, приходящий через функцию аякс (ответ в виде текста), как сделать, чтобы в этом куске работали jQuery или JavaScript функции? Например, самый простой вариант

ajax

```
function Simple() {
    var Req = null;
    Req = getXmlHttpRequest();
    Req.open("GET", "server.php", true);
    Req.send(null);
    Req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (Req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (Req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('tag').innerHtml = Req.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

php

Ну, например, здесь идет так

```
<?php 
bla bla bla.... nujniy kod 
echo 'result';
?>
<script>  alert('check')</script>
```

Все работает, но кроме JavaScript и jQuery. Кто поможет, спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Mixail - просто выполнить код, они и так будут работать.

Comment: не работают же вот например если поставить какой то любой код яваскрипт то он не отрабатывается

Comment: значит у вас ошибка в коде, который приходит в ответе, либо что-то в таком духе

Comment: @Mixail, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Ошибка здесь:  

    document.getElementById('tag').innerHtml
надо:  

    innerHTML

Comment: нет никакой ошибки все нормально работает кроме яваскрипт я знаю примерно почему не работает но как сделать не знаю

Comment: @Mixail вам уже написали о вашей ошибки - вместо innerHtml нужно innerHTML

Comment: а это здесь так) я писал здесь в поле а в коде большими буквами

Answer (score 3):

Если надо запустить какой-то скрипт, который приходит в респонсе, то надо использовать команду

```
eval(code)
```

если всё в перемешку как у вас:

```
<?php 
bla bla bla.... nujniy kod 
echo 'result';
?>
<script id="eval">  alert('check')</script>​​​​​​​
```

то можно например скрипту добавить id и запускать так:

```
code = $('#eval').text();
eval(code);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eGP7C/  пример  ​

Answer (score 2):

У вас ответ от php в виде текста приходит в js-переменную на стороне клиента.
Обычно, чтобы интерпретировать этот ответ как js-код его обрабатывают функцией eval.

Т.е. вам нужно сделать что-то типа `eval(Req.responseText)`, где `Req.responseText` должен быть валидным js-кодом.
Вместо `<script>  alert('check')</script>` напишите просто `alert('check');`(но вывод php перед алертом тоже должен быть js-кодом)

Comment: очень мудро! но дело в том что здесь для примера я написал кратко а в реальном коде ситуация такая есть функция аякс которая гуляет на сервер и возращает результат в виде хтмл и эта функция прописана в виде цикла например идет раз вернул один идет второй раз вернул один и три например, и так далее много много раз  так что хтмльного кода на сервере до фигища поэтому менять или писать заново джейсоном или чем нибудь еще нет времени и желания вы похоже очень хорошо знаете яваскрипт и аякс может есть что то что можно написать на клиенте чтобы отрабатываля в возвращаемой части кода

Comment: По идее, в Вашей ситуации, если сервер возвращает html+произвольный JS, можно тупо сначала распарсить ответ: собрать отдельно все куски JS из тегов <script>, вырезать их, вставить остальной HTML, а выбранные куски уже eval(...). 
Не очень хорошее решение, конечно.
На самом деле, насколько я помню, если в подгружаемом HTML есть куски JS с $(document).ready(function(){...код...}), то браузеры нормально отрабатывают, считая наступление события $(document).ready - после подгрузки нового html. Соответственно, я бы посоветовала попробовать модифицировать возвращаемый JS

Answer (score 1):

Правильное решение очень простое! Вынести нужный код в яваскрипт функцию и дописать после ответа вот так

```
function Simple() {
    var Req = null;
    Req = getXmlHttpRequest();
    Req.open("GET", "server.php", true);
    Req.send(null);

    function Solution() {
        // код функции...
    }
    Req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (Req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (Req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('tag').innerHtml = Req.responseText;
            Solution();
        }
    }
}
```

И как я сразу не въехал. Короче, если кто-то замается, то вот пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 1):

> document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML = Req.responseText

Этот код вставит фрагмент разметки, но скрипты при этом не будут выполнены.

Попробуйте метод [jQuery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/). В комментарии [Karl Swedberg](http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-67912032) сказано, что он вставляет фрагмент html, при этом находит и выполняет скрипты.

Пример:

```
$('#tag').empty().append($(responseText))
```

Comment: спасибо! в будущем попрактикую этот метод но в данном случае я решил уже и  выложил здесь решение

Comment: Вот так кстати точно работает:  

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = '(' + responseText.toString() + ')();';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);